# How to remove box shadow between two divs to be like on same plane?

Tags: css

I would like to build an installer application with several steps.

When I applied box shadow, the adjacent part behaves not as I expected.

How to make adjacent divs look like on same plane?

```css
.step,
.content {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
}

.step {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 39px 0 0 39px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.dialog {
  display: flex;
  
}

.steps {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot for expected behavior.

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add an `:after` to your `.step` elements to hide the shadow.

```
.step:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    left: calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```css
.step,
.content {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  background-color: white;
}

.step {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 39px 0 0 39px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.step:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    left: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.dialog {
  display: flex;
  
}

.steps {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

If you want only the active tab to be fully white, you can add an `active` class to the active tab like so:

```css
.step,
.content {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  background-color: white;
}

.step {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 39px 0 0 39px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.step.active:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    left: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.dialog {
  display: flex;
  
}

.steps {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step active"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Another way *could* be to move the shadow of the tabs to the right side and put the z-index of your tabs above the actual content. But I never had good results with it because the shadow will not be the same on each side.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `box-shadow`, you can give the whole container [`filter: drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()). It casts shadow by its visible contents, not the bounding box.

But that means you have to make its content visible such as assigning `background-color` to them:

```css
.step, .content {
  background-color: white;
}

.step {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 39px 0 0 39px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.dialog {
  display: flex;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.steps {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add active step highlighted with adding another class like below:

in css:

```
.active {
 box-shadow:none;
 background-color:yellow;/* highlighted active  */
}
```

in the html:

```
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step active">Step1</div>
    <div class="step">Step2</div>
    <div class="step">Step3</div>
    <div class="step">Step4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a background-color and use a drop-shadow filter :

example below with a `background` + `box-shadow` Vs `filter:drop-shadow()`

```css
.step,
.content {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
  background: white;
}
.bis .step,
.bis .content {
  box-shadow: 0 0;
}



.bis {
  filter: drop-shadow( 0 2px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%));
}

.step {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 39px 0 0 39px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.dialog {
  display: flex;
}

.steps {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"><code>box-shadow</code></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="dialog bis">
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
    <div class="step"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"><code>drop-shadow()</code></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.step, .content { box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 16%); }
.step::after { content: " "; background: #fff; position: absolute; top: 0; right: -8px; width: 16px; height: 100%; }
.step { width: 100px; height: 30px; border-radius: 39px 0 0 39px; margin-bottom: 5px; position: relative; }
.content { width: 300px; height: 200px; }
.dialog { display: flex; }
.steps { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
  <div class="dialog">
    <div class="steps">
      <div class="step"></div>
      <div class="step"></div>
      <div class="step"></div>
      <div class="step"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
```